# jQuery load() function in ajax call doesn't work for scripts

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload

I searched a bit and almost all methods are taking script codes into another page and calling them. But I don't wanna do like that, I want it to reload dynamically. Is there any method that I can write in the AJAX code?

```
success: function(response) {
    $("button[name=post]").attr('disabled',false);
    $("button[name=post]").html('Post');
    $("#alertpost").fadeIn().html(response);
    $("#card_about").load(location.href + " #card_about>*","");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you really want to do. can you explain more?

Comment: Im trying to reload an element in the page, by using jQuery load(). It works, but js codes doesn't reload.

Comment: What does "js codes doesn't reload" mean?

Comment: load(); function reloads html tags. But not js codes between <script> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the div like this.Please mind the space before divid (" #card_about");

`$("#card_about").load(" #card_about");`

There is no need for `location.href` etc.

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'm asking. I tried your way too but JS codes between <script> tags doesn't work after load().

Comment: you can put your js code into a seperate file and then load it like this:

`$(‘#card_about’).load(“#card_about”,function(){
$.getScript(“js/custom.js”);
});`

Comment: Isn't there any method for loads them in same page?

Comment: Js codes contains Php codes too. So it doesn't work in another page :(